# Referencing a function parameter in R

Tags: r, function, parameter-passing

I'm working on a function and need to know how to reference the incoming parameters.

For example, in python or lots of other languages, you can reference the input parameters something like this:

```
sys.argv[1:].
```

How can I reference the name of a parameter in R?

The specific problem I'm trying to solve is I want to capture the string value of the incoming parameter, so I can paste it as a concentration with a list of column_names I want to iterate through.

Here's the head of the function call, just so you can see the incoming parameter:

```
function(df_in)
```

So here's an example of the code I am writing and I want the string value of the dataframe_in, not the object that it references.

```
col_name <-paste(df_in,varnames[i],sep="$")
```

if df_in contained "my_df" and the current column_name is my_col, I'm trying to have col_name in the example above set to my_df$my_col.

I was thinking of using the get() function but quite sure how to apply it in this situation.

Thanks

Comment: The first line of your function should probably be something like `df <- substitute(df_in)`. Then you can use `eval(df)` instead of `get()`  And unevaluated, `df` can be used as a name in `paste` as well

Comment: I don't really follow, but maybe this helps: `deparse(substitute(df_in))` will give you "df_in", and instead of `$` you can (should) use `[[]]` to access a variable in non-interactive use.

Comment: Thanks baptiste - I check-marked the answer below, but you were also correct with the deparse function. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
fn1 <- function(df_in){ in_nam <- deparse(substitute(df_in) )
         col_names <-paste(in_nam, names(df_in), sep="$")
         cat(col_names) }

> dfrm <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=letters[1:10])
> fn1(dfrm)
#dfrm$a dfrm$b
```

You didn't say what `varnames` was supposed to be so I'm guessing you want the column names from the object. BTW, don't expect to be able to reference the column values with those character values. They are no longer language objects.

Comment: Yes, it will be the output of a names(df_in) command. Thanks, I will try this solution.

Comment: The R terminology used to describe this is that `substitute` returns a language object and `deparse` takes an unevaluated expression and returns a character representation.

Comment: The deparse(substitute()) method worked great. The eval(substitute()) didn't seem to have an impact and still retained/referenced the underlying dataframe. Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: You would expect eval(substitute(.)) to return the value of the data object rather than the name under which it is stored in the workspace. The R terminology in this area can be a bit confusing since `dfrm` is a 'name' ( a language object)  but the `names` function returns a character value rather than a list of R 'names'. Further terminology: `df_in` is a formal parameter. Look at `?formals`.